# ldapmodify: invalid format (line 4) entry: "olcDatabase={2},cn=config"

Tags: linux, synchronization, redhat, openldap, slapd

New to Openldap (2.4.40). I am getting this error when running:

```
ldapmodify -a -x -H "ldaps://localhost:636" -D "cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -W -f  olcsyncrepl.ldif
```

Error:

> ldapmodify: invalid format (line 4) entry: “olcDatabase={2},cn=config”

This is the ldif file:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=123
    provider=ldaps://sso.provider.com
    binddn="cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
    bindmethod=simple
    credentials=mypassword
    searchbase="dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
    attrs="cn,sn,displayName,givenName,mail,uid"
    type=refreshAndPersist
    retry="10 6 60 +"
```

I am not sure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Indented code. Copied error message from title to body.

Comment: That's not it, It's probably the way I pasted it to the question. The ldif file has all the lines to the left, no indention. It's weird, I read somewhere else to put the oldSyncrepl code in one line, and I actually got a different error after doing that.

Comment: The new error is 'ldap_add: Object class violation (65) additional info: no objectClass attribute' I added objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig, then  it asked me for the rootDN, BaseDN. Now I am getting this other error: ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80) additional info: <olcSyncrepl> failed startup. It's getting exhausting. I might just delete the entire slapd.d directory, make the changes to the slapd.conf, and let the application convert it to cn=config

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up adding the Syncrepl to the slapd.conf file, then re-convert it to cn=config, and it went through just fine. After making a few other changes, replication is finally working

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `{0}`and `{2}`. OpenLDAP will put in the sequence numbers.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. What would the first line look like without the {2}? I've seen samples of olcSyncrepl without the { }, but I haven't seen one of the olcDatabase without the { }.